# Window Phone Game 4.0: No target available for deployment

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xna, target, deploying

I am following instructions in the book "Windows Phone 7 Game Development" (Adam Dawes) as part of my university course. I am mentioning the name of the book in case this is important to anyone. Anyway, I am following the instruction for "Your First XNA Project" in chapter two, but every time that I try to run the project with or without debugging I am presented with the error "No target is available for deploying". I have been unable to find a solution besides deleting the "Phone Tools" folder in "AppData/Local/Microsoft", but that didn't help. Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Just so you know, it doesn't matter if I try to run the default project or if I add more code to it as it says in the book: I always get the same error. Also, I am using Windows 8 and chose the option "Windows Phone OS 7.1" when creating the project if that's of any interest.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me that you are selecting the option to "deploy your game to a device" instead of using the [emulator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff434574(v=xnagamestudio.40).aspx).

Be careful when chosing the start method, as shown on the picture.

[image]

You can find a guide on how to deploy and debug your windows phone games on [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff434571(v=xnagamestudio.40).aspx).

Keep in mind that you may be missing the emulators on your PC, depending on what SDK/complement you installed. If this is the case, you can find all the necessary tools [here](http://dev.windows.com/en-us/develop/downloads).